# Rails / ActiveRecord: avoid two threads updating model at the same time with locks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's say I need to be sure `ModelName` can't be updated at the same time by two different Rails threads; this can happen, for example, when a webhooks post to the application tries to modify it at the same time some other code is running.

Per [Rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html), I think the solution would be to use `model_name_instance.with_lock`, which also begins a new transaction.

This works fine and prevents simultaneous UPDATES to the model, but it does not prevent other threads from reading that table row while the `with_lock` block is running.

I can prove that `with_lock` does not prevent other READS by doing this:

- Open 2 rails consoles;
- On console 1, type something like `ModelName.last.with_lock { sleep 30 }`
- On console 2, type `ModelName.last`. You'll be able to read the model no problem.
- On console 2, type `ModelName.update_columns(updated_at: Time.now)`. You'll see it will wait for the 30 seconds lock to expire before it finishes.

This proves that the lock DOES NOT prevent reading, and as far as I could tell there's no way to lock the database row from being read.

This is problematic because if 2 threads are running the same method at the EXACT same time and I must decide to run the `with_lock` block regarding some previous checks on the model data, thread 2 could be reading stale data that would be soon be updated by thread 1 after it finishes the `with_lock` block that is already running, because thread 2 CAN READ the model while `with_lock` block is in progress in thread 1, it only can't UPDATE it because of the lock.

**EDIT: I found the answer to this question, so you can stop reading here and go straight to it below :)**

One idea that I had was to begin the `with_lock` block issuing a harmless update to the model (like `model_instance_name.update_columns(updated_at: Time.now)` for instance), and then following it with a `model_name_instance.reload` to be sure that it gets the most updated data. So if two threads are running the same code at the same time, only one would be able to issue the first update, while the other would need to wait for the lock to be released. Once it is released, it would be followed with that `model_instance_name.reload` to be sure to get any updates performed by the other thread.

The problem is this solution seems way too hacky for my taste, and I'm not sure I should be reinventing the wheel here (I don't know if I'm missing any edge cases). How does one assure that, when two threads run the exact same method at the exact same time, one thread waits for the other to finish to even read the model ?

Comment: Can you show a part of code, especially operations with the DB?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Thanks Robert for the Optimistic Locking info, I could definitely see me going that route, but Optimistic locking works by raising an exception on the moment of writing to the database (SQL UPDATE), and I have a lot of complex business logic that I wouldn't even want to run with the stale data in the first place.

This is how I solved it, and it was simpler than what I imagined.

First of all, I learned that pessimistic locking **DOES NOT** preventing any other threads from reading that database row.

But I also learned that `with_lock` also initiates the lock immediately, regardless of you trying to make a write or not.

So if you start 2 rails consoles (simulating two different threads), you can test that:

- If you type `ModelName.last.with_lock { sleep 30 }` on Console 1 and `ModelName.last` on Console 2, Console 2 can read that record immediately.
- However, if you type `ModelName.last.with_lock { sleep 30 }` on Console 1 and `ModelName.last.with_lock { p 'I'm waiting' }` on Console 2, Console 2 will wait for the lock hold by console 1, even though it's not issuing any write whatsoever.

So that's a way of 'locking the read': if you have a piece of code that you want to be sure that it won't be run simultaneously (not even for reads!), begin that method opening a `with_lock` block and issue your model reads inside it that they'll wait for any other locks to be released first. If you issue your reads outside it, your reads will be performed even tough some other piece of code in another thread has a lock on that table row.

Some other nice things I learned:

- As per [rails documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html), `with_lock` will not only start a transaction with a lock, but it will also reload your model for you, so you can be sure that inside the block `ModelName.last` is on it's most up-to-date state, since it issues a `.reload` on that instance.
- That are some gems designed specifically to block the same piece of code running at the same time in multiple threads (which I believe the majority of every Rails app is while in production environment), regardless of the database lock. Take a look at redis-mutex, redis-semaphore and redis-lock.
- That are many articles on the web (I could find at least 3) that state that Rails `with_lock` will prevent a READ on the database row, while we can easily see with the tests above that's not the case. Take care and always confirm information testing it yourself! I tried to comment on them warning about this.

Comment: Blocking the reads is really not the best practice. I hope you know what you are doing.

Comment: @RobertPankowecki In our case, it was justified because we have payment gateway that can return an authorized charge imediatelly (in line), but it can also  notify our end via webhooks later on. The problem is this 'later on' can be (and it was in production) a few miliseconds later, so we faced raced conditions that the inline code was processing an authorized payment and the webhooks was doing it as well (simultaneosly). We made our code idempotent by not caring if the webhooks got called repeteadly, but we need to make sure to lock the read so we know only one thread is running code.

Comment: excellent and helpful discussion of a thorny issue especially the correction re READ not being prevented by with_lock in another thread

Answer (score 2):

You were close, you want optimistic locking instead of pessimist locking: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Optimistic.html .

It won't prevent reading an object and submitting a form. But it can detect that the form was submitted when the user was seeing stale version of the object.